# iOS NESTDK from Github

Tags: ios, account

I'd like to try how NESTDK works in iOS. So I found and downloaded its [source code](https://github.com/nestlabs/iOS-NestDK) from Github NestLab. As instructed, I replaced my NestClientID and NestClientSecret in Constant.m, leaving all other fields (NestCurrentAPIDomain, NestState, RedirectURL) unchanged. Then I built and ran.

Screen 1: "Connect with your nest account" <-- I tapped on it

Screen 2: "Connect with Nest" title, Works with Nest... <-- I tap on "Accept" at the bottom of the page

Screen 3: enter my NEST developer email & password

Screen 4: PINCODE displayed

I am not sure what to do next in Screen 4 since it leaves me no other options. If I press "Cancel" on the Navigation bar, the app takes me back to Screen 1.

After Screen 4, I expect to see a list of the simulated NEST devices (using Chrome plugin) which can be controlled from the app but actually I see no options to help me move forward.

Did you successfully run this sample code? Please show me how.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you need to change RedirecteURL to https://localhost in Constant.m and change Redirect URI from nest web site (Edit Product) to  https://localhost